# Connecting to Azure Key Vault using DataProtectionProvider

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I am having a heck of a time configuring .Net Core's DataProtectionProvider to store keys in an Azure Key Vault. The issue is that I can't seem to create a proper Blob URI, or at least I think that's the issue since everything else seems to be in order and yet I'm still getting Unauthorized.

In Azure I have registered an application and client secret, created an vault and a key, and an access policy giving pretty much all permissions to the application.

Here's the relevant part of my ConfigureServices:

```
        string uri = "https://{vault-name}.vault.azure.net/keys/{vault-name}/{key}" + "se=2020-01-01&sp=r&spr=https&sv=2018-11-09&sr=b&sig={sig}";
        string keyIdentifier = "https://{vault-name}.vault.azure.net/keys/{vault-name}";
        string clientId = "{application-id";
        string clientSecret = "{client-secret}";

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri(uri)) // requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage
            .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(keyIdentifier, clientId, clientSecret); //requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault
        services.AddControllers();
```

I'm hung up on how to generate the sas. The documentation seems to suggest that somehow this relates to a storage account, but I can't see any obvious way to relate a storage account to a key vault. So I've tried a few different things from the Azure CLI but nothing seems to get my past authentication.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass the uri for Key Vault to `.PeristKeysToAzureBlobStorage()`. Instead you need to pass the uri for the blob in storage that is going to hold the key ring. This is noted in the doc for the [Azure Storage provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#azure-storage).

You can generate the SAS link through the portal as pictured or you can [utilize the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli) to create the link.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this. It seems I didn't understand that I needed a storage container to go along with with the key vault. It makes sense now. This solution worked perfectly.